# Cannot claim builds in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

On our Jenkins (1.492) I have the [Claim Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Claim+plugin) installed. Jenkins is configured to use LDAP using matrix authorization.

After installing the plugin and enabling the plugin in the configuration of each job the /claim view says "Welcome to the Hudson Claim Report. There are no failing builds. Excellent work!" and does not list any builds to claim.

I have both unstable and failed builds.

- I have rebuilt the failing and unstable builds after installing the plugin and configuring the jobs.
- I have also changed the default view back to "All" - I read somewhere that there may be a problem.
- I did also restart Jenkins.
- I am logged in with an LDAP user.
- The claim view does not list anything.
- I have no claim icon in the build history of the job.
- I have no claim link on the build page beneathe "started by user".
- I have added a "Claim" column to a custom view with failing tests - but it's empty.
- But I can claim a single regression via the test report view on a unstable build.

What have I missed? How can I find the problem?

Comment: You may get a better response if you try either the jenkins-users mailing list, or report a bug at issues.jenkins-ci.org.

Comment: @jone As a simple troubleshooting step, I'd create a dummy job at your current Jenkins and test if it works with it. If not, then I'd fire up a clean Jenkins, add that plugin, and test there. If still doesn't work, you'll at least have excellent bug report material.

Comment: I have this issue too. I'm led to believe that you do the claiming from specific test failures, not from the builds themselves... but the Claim Report is always empty and I don't see any kind of claim feature anywhere in the UI. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

In order to activate the Claim Plugin you must first add the 'Allow broken build claiming' action to the 'Post-build Action' section of one or more jobs. The next time the job fails after adding this step, it should be available to claim.

Configuring this on a large number of jobs is a bit of a pain but fortunately someone has contributed a [Groovy script](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Allow+broken+build+claiming+on+every+jobs) to allow broken build claiming on every job.

Comment: Any idea on how to do this in pipelines jobs?  I found a bug that's meant to be fixed now, but it's not clear one how to use it: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39537